# GetLocaleInfo - More Help Needed - Delphi XE5

Tags: delphi

Firstly, I need to know the measurement units being used on a computer so I can set the constant for converting to twips (1440 or 567).  I've looked "everywhere" on the web and I'm having trouble working out whether I should be using GetLocaleInfo or GetLocaleInfoEx.  Could someone please explain the difference.

Secondly, I found an answer on this forum under "How to read and change the system measurement units in control panel regional and Language advanced settings".  It shows code for setting the measurement units but I'm having trouble setting the parameters for getting the info.  Could anyone give an example for the appropriate Function (GetLocaleInfo or GetLocaleInfoEx).

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I had tried both forms.  In each case I worked out the locale and type from the many examples available. However, as a bit of a novice, I was having a lot of difficulty working out what went into the 'lpLCData' and 'cchData' because I couldn't see the relevance to the resulting 0 or 1.  Also, I hadn't seen any reference to the Win32Check - I take it this is to trap any errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var
  L: array [0..1] of Char;
begin
  Win32Check(GetLocaleInfo(LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, LOCALE_IMEASURE, @L, 2));
  if L[0] = '0' then
    // metric
  else
    // US
```

```
var
  L: array [0..1] of Char;
const
  LOCALE_NAME_SYSTEM_DEFAULT = '!x-sys-default-locale';
begin
  Win32Check(GetLocaleInfoEx(LOCALE_NAME_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, LOCALE_IMEASURE, @L, 2) <> 0);
  if L[0] = '0' then
    // metric
```

`GetLocaleInfo` accepts a [locale identifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd373763(v=vs.85).aspx), `GetLocaleInfoEx` accepts a [locale name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd373814(v=vs.85).aspx). They both retrieve locale information. As documented, for Vista and up, it is suggested to use `GetLocaleInfoEx` for its support for custom locales.

Comment: The code worked great.  Thanks.  Is there any way to officially state that the problem is solved?

Comment: You're welcome. You can *accept* the answer, there's a check mark near the up-down arrows. Note that this is not the only way to call the function. The key is to locate the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd373786(v=vs.85).aspx). Once you know you have to pass a two character buffer, do it anyway you like. Win32Check is optional, what matters is to check for errors, that's all.